# autocovariance of arma

Tags: autocorrelation, arma

I have noticed that when people want to calculate variance or autocovariance they assume that mean is equal to 0. So I want to ask if i get some ARMA process with non-zero mean and I need to calculate autocovariance function can I just eliminate constant term in the equation and calculate autocovariances?

Comment: I guess you can find a precise answer in any time series book. However, think about simple correlation of two variables. Would it matter if you compute it either on the centred (e.g. with respect to the mean) or on the non centred variables?

Answer (score 2):

For ARMA models stationarity is assumed.  So the sample mean is an unbiased estimate of the mean of the process.  Just subtract the sample mean from each observation and you will have a series of observations with 0 mean.